# How to filter sql developer to only show my tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Coming from sqlserver world, I am a noob in the oracle/sql developer world. In the SQL Developer  , I only want to show the tables I created, but it is showing tons of extra tables which I don't need and i have to keep scrolling. The JOB table in the screenshot below is the only one that I want to see.

I tried creating a filter, ( a LIKE ) filter by right clicking the tables and choosing CREATE FILTER but I have tried many combinations of filters in that dialog box and I can't get just my JOB table to show and others ( I think all of the extra ones have a $ and _ in the name) to go away.

How do I filter them? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're logged in as a system user - you shouldn't be creating your tables in there.

You should create a separate user (it will have its own schema) and you'll only see the tables you create.

Answer (score 23):

The answer about not creating tables as a system user is correct.  In the meantime, you can filter out these tables with settings like these:

[image: ii]

For easy copy pasting, here's the list:

- `AQ$%`
- `DEF$%`
- `LOGMNR%`
- `LOGSTD%`
- `MVIEW%`
- `REPCAT%`
- `OL$%`

Comment: This is also great for filtering out users you don't want to see if you have 5 kajillion like I do. (kajillion is the platonic ideal for large numbers as a class)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you have logged in as a SYS user. 
If you dot want to see the system tables, then apply simple filter like below

Name -> NOT LIKE -> %$%

All table with $ in it will be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

I think It's not possible. But you can query your table through your own **SCHEMA**

Like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = '[some other schema]'
```

(OR)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_TABLES 
WHERE OWNER='OTHER-SCHEMA'
```